# PHP / NetSuite - nsComplexObject Doesn't Exist

Tags: php, netsuite

I am not certain if I am maybe misunderstanding, something in the examples I see, but any time I try to make sure of nsComplexObject, I get an error that it does not exist.

I am specifically trying to create a sales order.  I set up my array of values, but when I try to do the following, I get an error:

```
<?php
require_once '../PHPToolkit/NetSuiteService.php';
$service = new NetSuiteService();

$salesOrder = new nsComplexObject('SalesOrder');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking at older Toolkit examples.

The newer versions (I think since 2012_2) use a different method for instantiating objects, such as:

```
$salesOrder = new SalesOrder();
```

You can still use the setFields method to populate object properties, but you can also populate them directly now:

```
$salesOrder->entity = $someRecordRefObject;
```

Comment: Seems about right.  I am still a bit lost in their Schema Browser and the samples are kind of thin so far.

Comment: Look around Stack Overflow. I've published lots of sample code for people who are having trouble. There is a learning curve, for sure, but once you get it, it's not terribly hard to work with.